# Installing PySide - OSX

Tags: c++, python, cmake, pyside

Anyone had success installing and using PySide on OSX? I am following the install instructions on the PySide site, though I'm running into issues building the API Extractor. I run `cmake` on the CMakeLists.txt file inside the api extractor dir and:

This error is thrown-

```
CMake Error at /Applications/CMake 2.8-0.app/Contents/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:894 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root
  directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing
  Boost's headers.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)
```

I am new to building source w/ cmake and I'm not event really sure what Boost is. Any light you might shed on the set up process would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a set of quite widespread C++ libraries, they're probably needed by PySide, even though I've never tried it.

Download them from there:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.42.0/

Otherwise, you can install them from macports: http://www.macports.org once you've installed macports, just run "sudo port install boost". Unluckily, pyside itself doesn't seem to be in macports yet.

Comment: thanks, yeah i was really hoping to find an install through mac ports

Answer (score 4):

You may want to check the newest release of PySide, out very recently, I believe the dependency on the Boost libraries has been removed.